# How to block the event loop until finish running async tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, event-loop

Let's assume that we have a web server that receives http requests and send responses back. It has many endpoints including this one

`/task` should has some async tasks like reading/writing from `Redis`, I want to block the event loop until those tasks are finished. I know it is not reasonable because the event loop needs also to keep working to receive the events for `Redis`. So I am thinking about putting this logic in a separate script and use `child_process.spawnSync` to execute and wait for it and block the current event loop. This solution will work but my problem is my logic and the async tasks are more complex than what mentioned in this sample, they have dependencies to the current script and they are part of the framework, it is not easy to separate them to a separated script. Any suggestions ?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('./redis');

// Block the event loop until finish doing some async tasks
app.get('/task', function(req, res) {

  // Block the event loop now
  redis.get('backup', function(error, backup) {

    // ...... Do some changes to the backup data

    redis.set('backup', backup, function(error, result) {

      // Unblock the event loop now
      res.send('I am done');

    });

  });

});

// To check if the event loop is really blocked
counter = 0;
setInterval(() => { console.log(counter++) }, 100);

app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: `Any suggestions ?`, yes. don't block.  It's not clear why in your description you need too..

Comment: It is not important why I need to block, the question is how to. Anyway I need to backup some sessions status into Redis and prevent receiving events that may invalidate these data until finish storing the current sessions status into Redis then continue handling the received events in between, that why I need to block the event loop to let those events to be queued and prevent race conditions.

Comment: You can do all of that without blocking the main thread.  Anyway you said any suggestions, that's mine.  If this is a multi-user website, doing this will cripple it.

Comment: I don't think that blocking the event loop is an option also. Maybe raising a global flag or using some other mechanism will work for you. For example `// Block the event loop now` -> `global.EVENT_LOOP_BLOCKED = true`. Now use this variable to return something like _server is busy right now_ response to all requests that interact with Redis and when you finish the job just `global.EVENT_LOOP_BLOCKED = false`

Comment: @codtex Indeed, you can even just apply this to a single middleware, you don't even need to implement on all the requests..

Comment: @Keith yes thats true, event more elegant solution :)

Comment: It seems this will solve my problem
https://github.com/Wizcorp/locks

Comment: No, it doesn't block the main thread, you will still get requests..

Comment: If what your after is preventing requests to your website while your backing up, doing what @codtex said, and using a simple middleware that checks this flag is really nice solution to the problem.  The bonus is your middleware could reply with a nice message `Server Maintenance in operation, please try again later".  Instead of a website that just doesn't respond with anything, not even a 404.  Is there something else you need to block Node's event loop for.  btw.. Just trying to help, if you want me leave I'll go.

Comment: Not preventing requests, but let them wait.

Comment: You can do that too,.  just make the middleware wait to call next, until flag is set.   Please note, client requests will terminate from client end anyway after a certain amount of time.  eg. if your backup took 20mins, you can't make the client wait that long on a request.

Comment: How to keep checking that flag ?

Comment: Just use a setInterval, your next can be kept inside a closure. Would you like me to knock up a quick snippet for an example?  Or even better you could use an Event, https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v7.x/api/events.html

Comment: Well, no good solution in node.js comes from blocking the event loop, so you should tell us the real problem you're trying to solve and then we can help you better with a good solution.  What you have here is an XY problem where you just described a problem with your solution, but that solution is a dead-end path and because you didn't describe the actual problem, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You would have to re-write all applicable code to work with Promises or use a library that does so for you.

Your primary function might look something like this;

```
(async function main(){
 try{

 await taskFunction();
 await backupGetFunction();
 await backupSetFunction();
  res.send('I am done');

 } catch (error){
  throw error;
 }; 

})();
```

Everything will be executed in order and at the end, it will res.send 'I am done' as expected.

The complexity behind this solution is that any functions that rely on the main function will need to be using promises in order to keep the flow asynchronous.

As an example, your backup function might initially be;

```
function backupExample(){
 fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
 console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
};
```

When it must be converted to the following to work with async/await;

```
function backupExample(){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
 resolve('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
  });
 });
};
```

The promises act as guidance to the primary async/await function so it knows when async functions have completed.

Comment: Updated as per your request, egon12.

Comment: I think `async function backUpExample` doesn't need `async` keyword because it already return `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use.

```
redis.getAsync('backup')
.then(res => {

// ...... Do some changes to the backup data
 return redis.set('backup', backup)
})
.then(()=>res.send('I\'m done'))
```

or

```
   let backup = await redis.getAsync('backup');
    // ...... Do some changes to the backup data
   redis.set('backup', backup);
   res.send('I\'m done');
```

note if you use async/await features you need to have at least node v7 and up. or --harmony-async-await flag when running the node